# How to mock an interface returned as property from another mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, fakeiteasy

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface IManufacturing
{
    IJobApi JobApi {get;}
}

interface IJobApi
{
    IList<JobSpec> GetSpecs (string wo, string name);
}
```

I have a class which uses IManufacturing and calls GetSpecs() like so:

```
var specs = _manufacturing.JobApi.GetSpecs (wo, name);
```

I setup my mocks like:

```
var jobApi = A.Fake<IJobApi> ();
A.CallTo (() => jobApi.GetSpecs (It.IsAny<string> (), It.IsAny<string> ()))
            .Invokes (() => System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("GetSpecs called!"))
            .Returns (new List<JobSpec>
                      {
                          new JobSpec("blablabla", "0.125", "something")
                      });

var manufacturing = A.Fake<IManufacturing> ();
A.CallTo (() => manufacturing.JobAPI)
            .Invokes (() => System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine ("JobAPI called!"))
            .Returns (jobApi);
```

Upon running the test, I only see the "JobAPI called" string in the output.
So, the GetSpecs() does not get mocked and indeed the caller throws because it expected a list of specs whereas it received an empty string...

What could be the culprit here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dammit!

You're gonna laugh, I have!

Turned out that the following line

```
A.CallTo (() => jobApi.GetSpecs (It.IsAny<string> (), It.IsAny<string> ()))
```

was not correct for FakeItEasy. It should be written as

```
A.CallTo (() => jobApi.GetSpecs (A<string>.Ignored, A<string>.Ignored))
```

So, you may wonder why it did compile and run... Yeah me too. ;)

It.IsAny is for Moq (!)

I had a Using Moq lingering at the top of the class. (I'm in the process of switching to fakeiteasy from moq).

[face palm]

TGIF

Comment: +1 for honesty. I think people can still learn from things like this.